# Some products can't be added to cart from a particular store

Tags: product, multistore

I have an install where multiple stores are being used and some products are common across all stores.

The issue is with one of the store, the url `http://domain.lo/store2/checkout/cart/add?product=327&qty=1` doesn't add the product to cart but session message does show up on cart page saying product was successfully added. I tried to use a debugger but didn't find anything wrong in the execution flow, it works correctly as far as I can tell.

The product is definitely in stock and works fine on main & other stores. Even its product page loads fine directly but that doesn't load on store2, one in which I have the problem. So, I reindexed everything but still no luck.

Out of ideas how to troubleshoot it further. Any pointers?

Comment: do you get anything logged in var/log?

Comment: @Marius Nope, nothing! Even with jumping through a debugger, I didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: @Marius Tried with developer mode, error logs & moving out community & local modules, didn't help.

Comment: Is your other store on http://domain.lo/ - if yes do you have an active session (frontend cookie) from this store. Also does it work when using the uenc version of the add to cart link (like /checkout/cart/add/uenc/XYZ...) ?

Comment: @Fooman Can't test now since we deleted those products and created again to get rid of the issue. Regarding your ques, yes user sessions are maintained independently on each store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the products from fresh and that made it work, looks like it was a hiccup with how a few products were saved.